# I want use Java Function in Android Project

Tags: java, android, function

I have a function. This function worked in Java Project. But I want this function use Android Project. While I was using. Project get "unfortunately .. has stopped. Do you help mi ?

Function

```
public String yandex_translate(String yandex_lang,String yandex_text) throws IOException, ParseException{

    String yandex_key = "****";


    String yandex_url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key="+yandex_key+"&lang="+yandex_lang+"&text="+yandex_text;


    URL url = new URL(yandex_url);

        URLConnection httpUrlConnection = url.openConnection();

        InputStream inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));


        String line=bufferedReader.readLine();


        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();


        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(line);;


        JSONArray msg = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("text");

        if(jsonObject.get("code").toString().equals("200")){
            return msg.get(0).toString();
        }else{
            return "Çeviri yapılırken bir hata oluştu.";
        }
}
```

function using

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String a;
    try {
         a = yandex_translate("en-tr","book");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        a = e.getMessage();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        a = e.getMessage();
    }
    tvKelime.setText(a);
}
```

---

```
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at com.example.deneme.MainActivity.yandex_translate(MainActivity.java:113)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at com.example.deneme.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:92)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-06 19:14:25.128: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You could write what type of error you get or the exception

Comment: Post your `LogCat` showing the exception and call stack.

Answer (score 1):

You should move your code to work in a different thread (in this case Asynctask)

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread.
>
> This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
>   thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.
>
> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler
>   and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks
>   should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the
>   most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time,
>   it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and
>   FutureTask.
>
> An asynchronous task is defined by a computation that runs on a
>   background thread and whose result is published on the UI thread. An
>   asynchronous task is defined by 3 generic types, called Params,
>   Progress and Result, and 4 steps, called onPreExecute, doInBackground,
>   onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute.

It's how you could write it:

```
private class AsyncRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    // private because if someone calls this method without the syntax i said the exception will appear again
    private String yandex_translate(String yandex_lang,String yandex_text) throws IOException, ParseException
    {

        String yandex_key = "****";


        String yandex_url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key="+yandex_key+"&lang="+yandex_lang+"&text="+yandex_text;


        URL url = new URL(yandex_url);

        URLConnection httpUrlConnection = url.openConnection();

        InputStream inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));


        String line=bufferedReader.readLine();


        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();


        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(line);;


        JSONArray msg = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("text");

        if(jsonObject.get("code").toString().equals("200")){
            return msg.get(0).toString();
        }else{
            return "Çeviri yapılırken bir hata oluştu.";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        return yandex_translate(params[0], params[1]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        tvKelime.setText(s);
    }
}
```

then to use it

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new AsyncRequest("en-tr","book").execute();
}
```

The `EditText` will be updated when finished.

[Asynctask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

[`onPostExecute`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) and [`onPreExecute`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29) are called in the UI thread, so you can update your UI here.

`doInBackground` is called in the worker thread, avoid every UI edit from here! If you really need, use `runOnUiThread` method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to put this in your manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

I am just guessing but it is worth a try. Please provide your logs to get proper help.

Comment: I have this permission.